# Why do I get a checkout failed?

Tags: windows, git

I am trying to clone a repo and getting an error :

```
Cloning into '****'...                                                                                                                        
remote: Counting objects: 5125, done.                                                                                                         
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3969/3969), done.                                                                                          
remote: Total 5125 (delta 1006), reused 4569 (delta 761)                                                                                      
Receiving objects: 100% (5125/5125), 5.07 MiB | 7.87 MiB/s, done.                                                                             
Resolving deltas: 100% (1006/1006), done.                                                                                                     
Checking connectivity... done.                                                                                                                
warning: unable to access '***-frontend/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/gauge/node_modules/lodas
h.padright/node_modules/lodash._createpadding/node_modules/lodash.repeat/.gitattributes': Filename too long                                   
fatal: cannot create directory at '****-frontend/node/node_modules/package/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/gauge/node_m
odules/lodash.padleft/node_modules/lodash._createpadding/node_modules/lodash.repeat': Filename too long                                       
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.                                                                                                
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'                                                                                        
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

The question is why I get this error and how to avoid it? Also when I run git status , all files show up as marked DELETED?

When I run git checkout -f HEAD I get :

```
warning: unable to access '****-frontend/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/gauge/node_modules/lodas
h.padright/node_modules/lodash._createpadding/node_modules/lodash.repeat/.gitattributes': Filename too long
```

Comment: Have you eliminated the filename errors as irrelevant to the problem ?  The error reports as "filename" too long, but I suspect the issue is really the path length.  The path in the error is 200+ character long, so if you are cloning into a location with "deep" path itself then this could be your problem.  Have you tried cloning into a folder directly off your root, for example ?

Comment: Also, it looks like you are cloning the node_modules folder in a Node.js project, and you shouldn't do that. You should put the node_modules folder in the .gitignore and run `npm install` after cloning

Comment: @Deltics what do you mean with cloning into a folder directly off your root?